# opengl 3d object picking - raycast

Tags: opengl, 3d, raycasting

I have a program displaying planes of cubes, like levels in a house, I have the planes displayed so that the display angle is consistent to the viewport projection plane. I would like to be able to allow the user to select them.

First I draw them relative to each other with the first square drawn at {0,0,0}

[image]

then I translate and rotate them, each plane has it's own rotate and translate.

[image]

Thanks to this [this](http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/using_gluunproject/16013/) page I have code that can cast a ray using the user's last touch. If you notice in the picture above, there is a green square and blue square, this is debug graphic displaying the ray intersecting the near and far planes in the projection matrix after clicking in the centre (with z of zero in order to display them), so it appears to be working.

I can get a bounding box of the cube, but it's coordinates will think they are still up in the left corner.

My question is how do I use my ray to check intersections with the objects after they have been rotated and translated? I'm very confused as I once had this working when I was translating and rotating the whole grid as one, now each plane is being moved separately I can't work out how to do it.

Comment: This is an experimental idea I just got from reading your post. You could do an 'anti-projection' of the click coordinates and then check where the player clicked in a 2D plane like in your first image. To do this take the inverse of your projection matrix and apply it to the click coordinates.

Comment: Why do you specifically need to use a ray to do this? The general term for what you're trying to do is called "picking", and it doesn't necessarily require rays.

Comment: I don't remeber why I decided to do it this way. I do remember I was doing it differently at one point, maybe depth was an issue, this way I know the distance to the camera. Anyway I seem to have solved things by simply translating and rotating the rayvector the same way the plains do. I don't know why that solves it though.